# How to rewrite 1 specifc line in the loop of a .txt file with PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am looping through a text file and searching for a token. When found, I need to replace that line with a new string.

How do I do that? I tried fwrite and I could not do it correctly.

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$alllines = explode("\n", $content); // this is your array of words

foreach ($alllines as $line) { //find requested token and check if it's virgin or not

    global $file;
    global $content;
    global $newtoken;
    global $token;
    $newtoken = md5(time());

    $words = explode("-", $line);
    //first word is token 2nd is opened or virgin

    if ($words[0] == $token) {
        //requested token found

        if ($words[1] != "opened") {
            echo "virgin token<br>";
            $newword = $words[0] . "-opened";
            //file_put_contents($file, $newword.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); //this adds the new string in the end of the file -- not good
            echo "<br>now rewritten";
        } else {
            echo "used token<br>";
        }

        exit;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
echo "token not found"; exit;
```

I would like to be able to replace that line under $newword with $newword value.

Comment: What is happening with the globals?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion. When you find the token and it is not yet `opened` then replace that line in the array and rewrite the file with the imploded array:

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$alllines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$newtoken = md5(time());
$tokenFound = false;
foreach ($alllines as $lineNumber => $line) { //find requested token and check if it's virgin or not
    $words = explode("-", $line);
    //first word is token 2nd is opened or virgin

    if ($words[0] == $token) {
        //requested token found
        $tokenFound = true;
        if ($words[1] != "opened") {
            echo "virgin token<br>";
            $alllines[$lineNumber] = $token.'-opened';
            file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $alllines), LOCK_EX);
            echo "<br>now rewritten";
        } else {
            echo "used token<br>";
        }
        break;
    }
}
if (!$tokenFound) {
    echo "token not found";
}
```